# Trouble with recursive Boost.Spirit parsing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am trying to model a parser for a subset of the C language, for a school project. However, I seem stuck in the process of generating recursive parsing rules for Boost.Spirit, as my rules either overflow the stack or simply do not pick up anything.

For example, I want to model the following syntax:

a ::= ... | A[a] | a1 op a2 | ...

There are some other subsets of syntax for this expression rule, but those are working without problems. For example, if I were to parse A[3*4], it should be read as a recursive parsing where A[...] (A[a] in the syntax) is the array accessor and 3*4 (a1 op a2 in the syntax) is the index.

I've tried defining the following rule objects in the grammar struct:

```cpp
qi::rule<Iterator, Type(), Skipper> expr_arr;
qi::rule<Iterator, Type(), Skipper> expr_binary_arith;
qi::rule<Iterator, Type(), Skipper> expr_a;
```

And giving them the following grammar:

```cpp
expr_arr %= qi::lexeme[identifier >> qi::omit['[']] >> expr_a >> qi::lexeme[qi::omit[']']];
expr_binary_arith %= expr_a >> op_binary_arith >> expr_a;
expr_a %= (expr_binary_arith | expr_arr);
```

where "op_binary_arith" is a qi::symbol<> object with the allowed operator symbols.

This compiles fine, but upon execution enters a supposedly endless loop, and the stack overflows. I've tried looking at the answer by Sehe in the following question: [How to set max recursion in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325709/how-to-set-max-recursion-in-boost-spirit).

However, I have been unsuccessful in setting a max recursion depth. Firstly, I failed to make it compile without errors for almost any of my attempts, but on the last attempt it built successfully, albeit with very unexpected results.

Can someone guide me in the right direction, as to how I should go about implementing this grammar correctly?

Comment: PEG grammars do not handle left-recursion well. In general you have to split out helper rules to write without left-recursion. Many of my expression grammar answers show the typical way of dealing with this in Spirit (assuming you also want to capture the values into an AST).

Comment: I've tried searching around for left-recursion elimination now, and I've found a few answers by you, but I'm not sure how to apply them to my own case. Additionally, I found an example C grammar here: http://boost-spirit.com/distrib/spirit_1_7_0/libs/spirit/example/application/c/c_grammar.cpp.

I'm very new to parsers (and the entire compiler theory area), so I do not quite understand the logics behind e.g. turning a left-recursive grammar into a right-recursive grammar (as seen with e.g. the 'postfix_expression' rule from the above link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEG grammars do not handle left-recursion well. In general you have to split out helper rules to write without left-recursion.

In your particular case, the goal production

```
a ::= ... | A[a] | a1 op a2 | ...
```

Seems a little off. This would allows `foo[bar]` or `foo + bar` but not `foo + bar[qux]`.

Usually, the choice between array element reference or plain identifier is at a lower level of precedence (often "simple expression").

Here's a tiny elaboration:

```
literal           = number_literal | string_literal; // TODO exapnd?

expr_arr          = identifier >> '[' >> (expr_a % ',') >> ']';
simple_expression = literal | expr_arr | identifier;
expr_binary_arith = simple_expression >> op_binary_arith >> expr_a;
expr_a            = expr_binary_arith | simple_expression;
```

Now you can parse e.g.:

```
for (std::string const& input : {
        "A[3*4]",
        "A[F[3]]",
        "A[8 + F[0x31]]",
        "3 * \"foo\"",
    })
{
    std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> ";

    It f=begin(input), l=end(input);
    AST::Expr e;

    if (parse(f,l,g,e)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << e << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\b";
    }
}
```

Which prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5ec781f90ea1316)</kbd>**

```
"A[3*4]" -> Parsed: A[3*4]
"A[F[3]]" -> Parsed: A[F[3]]
"A[8 + F[0x31]]" -> Parsed: A[8+F[49]]
"3 * \"foo\"" -> Parsed: 3*"foo"
```

> **NOTE** I deliberately left efficiency and operator precedence out of the picture for now.
>
> These are talked about in detail in other answers:
>
> - [Boost::Spirit Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464969/boostspirit-expression-parser/8468822#8468822)
> - [Implementing operator precedence with boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219969/implementing-operator-precedence-with-boost-spirit/24220293#24220293)
> - [Boost::Spirit : Optimizing an expression parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820298/boostspirit-optimizing-an-expression-parser)
>
> And many more

### Full Demo Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5ec781f90ea1316)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <experimental/iterator>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace AST {
    using Var = std::string;

    struct String : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
    };

    using Literal = boost::variant<String, intmax_t, double>;

    enum class ArithOp {
        addition, subtraction, division, multplication
    };

    struct IndexExpr;
    struct BinOpExpr;

    using Expr = boost::variant<
        Literal,
        Var,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<IndexExpr>,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<BinOpExpr>
    >;

    struct IndexExpr {
        Expr expr;
        std::vector<Expr> indices;
    };

    struct BinOpExpr {
        Expr lhs, rhs;
        ArithOp op;
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Literal const& lit) {
        struct {
            std::ostream& os;
            void operator()(String const& s) const { os << std::quoted(s); }
            void operator()(double d) const { os << d; }
            void operator()(intmax_t i) const { os << i; }
        } vis {os};
        boost::apply_visitor(vis, lit);
        return os;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ArithOp const& op) {
        switch(op) {
            case ArithOp::addition: return os << '+';
            case ArithOp::subtraction: return os << '-';
            case ArithOp::division: return os << '/';
            case ArithOp::multplication: return os << '*';
        }
        return os << '?';
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BinOpExpr const& e) {
        return os << e.lhs << e.op << e.rhs;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, IndexExpr const& e) {
        std::copy(
            begin(e.indices),
            end(e.indices),
            std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(os << e.expr << '[', ","));

        return os << ']';
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::IndexExpr, expr, indices)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::BinOpExpr, lhs, op, rhs)

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct G : qi::grammar<Iterator, AST::Expr()> {
    G() : G::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        identifier        = alpha >> *alnum;

        number_literal    =
            qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> >{}
          | "0x" >> qi::uint_parser<intmax_t, 16> {}
          |         qi::int_parser<intmax_t, 10> {}
          ;

        string_literal    = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_escape | ~char_('"')) >> '"';

        literal           = number_literal | string_literal; // TODO exapnd?

        expr_arr          = identifier >> '[' >> (expr_a % ',') >> ']';
        simple_expression = literal | expr_arr | identifier;
        expr_binary_arith = simple_expression >> op_binary_arith >> expr_a;
        expr_a            = expr_binary_arith | simple_expression;

        start = skip(space) [expr_a];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)
                (expr_a)(expr_binary_arith)(simple_expression)(expr_a)
                (literal)(number_literal)(string_literal)
                (identifier))
    }

  private:
    struct escape_sym : qi::symbols<char, char> {
        escape_sym() {
            this->add
                ("b", '\b')
                ("f", '\f')
                ("r", '\r')
                ("n", '\n')
                ("t", '\t')
                ("\\", '\\')
                ;
        }
    } char_escape;

    struct op_binary_arith_sym : qi::symbols<char, AST::ArithOp> {
        op_binary_arith_sym() {
            this->add
                ("+", AST::ArithOp::addition)
                ("-", AST::ArithOp::subtraction)
                ("/", AST::ArithOp::division)
                ("*", AST::ArithOp::multplication)
                ;
        }
    } op_binary_arith;

    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::Expr()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::IndexExpr(), Skipper> expr_arr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::BinOpExpr(), Skipper> expr_binary_arith;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::Expr(), Skipper> simple_expression, expr_a;
    // implicit lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::Literal()> literal, string_literal, number_literal;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::Var()> identifier;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    G<It> const g;
    for (std::string const& input : {
            "A[3*4]",
            "A[F[3]]",
            "A[8 + F[0x31]]",
            "3 * \"foo\"",
        })
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> ";

        It f=begin(input), l=end(input);
        AST::Expr e;

        if (parse(f,l,g,e)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << e << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\b";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much - I finally figured it out!